# Error: Lvalue required.Need an explanation

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0, y = 1;

    y == 1 ? n=0 : n=1;

    if(n)
        printf("Yes\n");
    else
        printf("No\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n = y == 1 ? 0 : 1;` ?

Comment: n = ( y == 1 ) ? 0 : 1; for readability.

Comment: `n =  y != 1`? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The ?: operator doesn't quite work like that. What you want to do is something like:

```
n = ((y == 1) ? 0 : 1);
```

In the more general case, if you want to perform actions based on a condition, use an `if`. The ?: operator is more for returning values based on the condition.